# Ethereum/Truffle/Solidity: Error: the tx doesn't have the correct nonce

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle, ganache

When running the truffle test, the following error comes on the console. What might be the issue causing this.

> Error: the tx doesn't have the correct nonce. account has nonce of: 7
>   tx has nonce of: 6

`function activateAirline(address airlineAddress) external payable returns(bool) {
        require(isOperational(), "Service is not available");
        require(msg.sender == airlineAddress, "You can only fund your airline");
        require(msg.value == 10 ether, "Please submit 10 ether to activate your airline");
        contractOwner.transfer(10 ether);
}`

This is my truffle initialization to run the contract script
[image]

This is my truffle migration file
[image]

This is my truffle test
[image]

This is my contract function
[image]

Comment: Add the code as text here, not as an image.

Comment: Added the code also.

Answer (score 0):

> "tx has nonce of: 6"

The way you used "TX" is not clearly defined. when it asks for the nonce, depending on what you're trying to do, it be the nonce of the address interacting with that contract method. can you post your code?